# How can I restart emacs and preserve my open buffers and interactive history?

Tags: session

As a follow-up to [What's the fastest way to reload my .emacs file when I make changes so all my affected buffers will pick up those changes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/635/whats-the-fastest-way-to-reload-my-emacs-file-when-i-make-changes-so-all-my-af)

It was suggested that the restart question should be asked separately.

Is there an easy way to reopen all the previous buffers **and keep the `M-p` interactive history for commands?**

Comment: Also relevant: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/restart-emacs-from-within-emacs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`desktop-save-mode` handles storing, and restoring, the buffer state of your session. It can also handle window and frames.
For persistence of variables across sessions, see `savehist-mode`. By default it handles the minibuffer history, but it's not limited to it. Another interesting thing that might be interesting to persist is for example the kill-ring.

In short:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(savehist-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'kill-ring) ;; for example
```

Comment: This is true only for Emacs 24.4 or later.

Comment: @Drew sorry, which part exactly ?

Comment: I was speaking about `desktop.el`, not `savehist`. The saving and restoring of windows and frames was added to `desktop.el` in Emacs 24.4. And support for buffers not associated with files.  IOW, pretty much all of it (about desktop). ;-)  There is support for buffers associated with files before 24.4, however.

Comment: Is there any similar solution in Emacs 24.3? I'm using 24.3.1.

Comment: No. As I said, it was added in Emacs 24.4. You can pick up the Emacs 24.4 version of libraries `desktop.el` and `frameset.el` (which is new in 24.4), and try using them with Emacs 24.3, however.