# Restart emacs from within emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs

I restart my emacs a lot. All I want to do is create a function that kills the current emacs, only to spawn a new one in it's stead. Ideally, this would also work in a TTY.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you kill and immediately restart so often?

Comment: I very actively develop my `.emacs.d`, which means I restart emacs to remove whatever garbage I've blasted into my environment. There are a few other use-cases where I do this, but that's the biggest.

Comment: @PythonNut, I think you need to reframe your question a bit.  Can you tell `bash` to restart after terminating?  Or `vi`?  Or any other process, as a rule?  No, because that is outside of their scope of concerns, and is properly handled externally.  In any case, what you really want is a way to *reinitialize* emacs, by clearing out its VM and re-running your init code (*without* killing its process).  That would be useful and proper to emacs.  I don't know if it exists, though :)

Comment: @harpo yes, I can get `bash` to restart with `exec bash`. I have no idea about vim.

Comment: @PythonNut, thanks, I did not know about `exec`!  I can definitely use that.

Comment: FWIW, I'm more inclined to start a *new* instance of Emacs to test config changes, rather then exiting and restarting. Why? Because if my code has an error then Emacs might not be able to load my config when I restart it, and at that point I can't actually get a running instance with my normal settings, so I have to use a less-familiar editing environment to fix the bug. It won't happen often, but it's annoying when it does. I can run `emacs -q` and fix the problem of course, but I prefer to keep a 'good' instance running at all times when hacking on my configuration, just to be safe.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note: I have wrapped the following in a package `restart-emacs` available [here](http://github.com/iqbalansari/restart-emacs).

---

Here is an alternate way to achieve what you want using pure elisp (not really since you rely on a shell). The trick is to spawn off another emacs process just before current emacs is killed.

```el
(defun launch-separate-emacs-in-terminal ()
  (suspend-emacs "fg ; emacs -nw"))

(defun launch-separate-emacs-under-x ()
  (call-process "sh" nil nil nil "-c" "emacs &"))

(defun restart-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  ;; We need the new emacs to be spawned after all kill-emacs-hooks
  ;; have been processed and there is nothing interesting left
  (let ((kill-emacs-hook (append kill-emacs-hook (list (if (display-graphic-p)
                                                           #'launch-separate-emacs-under-x
                                                         #'launch-separate-emacs-in-terminal)))))
    (save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
```

The code to start a GUI version of emacs is straightforward. The code to start emacs in a terminal is a bit tricky. It uses the fact that you can pass a string to `suspend-emacs` which would be passed as terminal input to the parent process (the shell). From the documentation

> (suspend-emacs &optional STUFFSTRING)
>
> Stop Emacs and return to superior process.  You can resume later. If
>   `cannot-suspend' is non-nil, or if the system doesn't support job
>   control, run a subshell instead.
>
> If optional arg STUFFSTRING is non-nil, its characters are stuffed to
>   be read as terminal input by Emacs's parent, after suspension.

So we basically suspend emacs just before it is killed tell the parent shell to resume currently suspended emacs (which is going to exit soon) and then launch another emacs process. Note that this does not work on platforms on which terminal emacs can/does not actually suspend but starts a subshell, for example on windows.

Comment: This does not work for me: when I run `sh -c "emacs &"` from the shell it stops with "`emacs: standard input is not a tty`" . (When I do `M-x restart-emacs` I don't even see that error message, Emacs just terminates.)

Comment: Works for me under X.  Won't work in a terminal because it redirects stdin and stdout to /dev/null; passing the parent tty to the subprocess is probably doable but trickier.

Comment: This works perfectly, and it actually scares me a bit. Why on earth is Emacs allowed to pass commands to its containing shell?

Comment: which keybinding do you use for that ?

Comment: I am getting `Symbol’s function definition is void: \,` error

Comment: As of 2023 (I'm on Emacs 29.1), ´M-x restart-emacs´ works out of the box, but only if I launch the Emacs server (GUI or otherwise) from the Terminal. If I start Emacs from an Automator app running a shell script, it doesn't work. (Maybe I need to add stuff to the Automator app).

Answer (score 32):

As far as I know you cannot tell Emacs to re-start after terminating, but you can set the exit code so that the process that started Emacs in the first place can detect that you want to re-start.

For example, this shell script re-starts Emacs if it exited with the code 123.

```shell
#!/bin/sh
while emacs -nw "$@"; [ $? = 123 ]; do :; done
```

Next, we define `kill-emacs-and-restart` that makes Emacs terminate with the exit code equal to the magic number recognized by the script:

```el
(defun kill-emacs-and-restart ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-emacs 123))
```

Now if you run Emacs via this script you can re-start by `M-x kill-emacs-and-restart` (or bind it to a key sequence).

Comment: Nice way of skirting around the problem! I'll accept this if you can tell me why `you cannot tell Emacs to re-start after terminating`. Is this a technical limitation?

Comment: @PythonNut: As far as I know the only way to re-start a process is by using one of the functions from the `exec...` family (on POSIX systems, anyway). [Emacs Lisp process control functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html#Subprocess-Creation) don't expose such low-level calls. I'm not an expert, though, so hopefully somebody more knowledgeable will chime in.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
As of emacs version `29.1` emacs now has the `restart-emacs` command built in.

> ** New command 'restart-emacs'.
> This is like 'save-buffers-kill-emacs', but instead of just killing
> the current Emacs process at the end, it starts a new Emacs process
> (using the same command line arguments as the running Emacs process).
> 'kill-emacs' and 'save-buffers-kill-emacs' have also gained new
> optional arguments to restart instead of just killing the current
> process.

From the [release notes](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=emacs-29#n701)

Answer (score 2):

Blatantly stolen from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114238/is-it-possibe-to-change-parent-shells-working-directory-programmatically

Assuming I've got the syntax right for embedding " in a string, this should do it.

```el
(defun restart-emacs ()
  (call-process "sh" nil nil nil "-c" "gdb -p $(ps h -o ppid -p $$) -ex 'call execl(\"/bin/sh\", \"/bin/sh\", \"-c\", \"exec emacs\")'"))
```

Comment: Please don't.  This bypasses *all* of Emacs' internal cleanup and discards *all* current state (e.g. modified buffers) *without confirmation*.

Comment: lunaryorn's warning is correct.