# Restart emacs daemon from within emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs, emacs-daemon

Very much like [Restart emacs from within emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/restart-emacs-from-within-emacs), except I'd like to do this for an emacs daemon and client.

Specifically, I'm interested in the terminal client, but of course being able to restart from the graphical client would be cool.

EDIT: A quick glance at the Emacs source makes it look like stuffing a string to the STDIN of a terminal hosting a client cannot be done. :( Perhaps there's some other way?

Comment: May be it's clear to someone that knows emacs what you mean but to me it's not totally clear. If you mean to reload the initialization file you can do `M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs` or where ever your init file is (could be `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as well). The other interpretation is if you want to start a server from within emacs. Then you would do `M-x server-start RET` and it will fire up the server.

Comment: @Sparx I want to kill the emacs process, start it again and reconnect.

Comment: `M-x server-start RET` kills both the emacs process and the emacsclient, if any. In any case, how's [this solution and comments](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5429/7045) different from what you're asking now?

Comment: @EmacsUser have you tried it? It doesn't work for a client/daemon.

Comment: So what's different in your question this time around?

Comment: @EmacsUser I would like to get it working on the daemon as well.